# Need to get a make a query where there is atleast one condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table like this:

```
Table: item
isBeautiful: Boolean
isGreat: Boolean
isAvaliable: Boolean
```

I want to make a query with Eloquent that gives me all the items that are avaliable and are either isBeautiful or isGreat, or both.

```
$avaliableitems = item::where("isAvaliable,1)
                  ->where("isBeautiful",1)
                   ->orWhere("isGreat",1)->get();
```

This is pseudocode, I know it doesn't work.

I know I can alwaysjust get item where isavaliable = 1 and then loop through each item and do:

```
foreach($avaliableitems as $avaliableitem){
if($avaliableitem->isBeautiful == 1 || $avaliableitem->isGreat){

//do things

}
}
```

But I wonder if there is a way to do it with Eloquent as mentioned before.

Comment: try this $avaliableitems = item::where("isAvaliable,1)
                  ->orwhere("isBeautiful",1)
                   ->orWhere("isGreat",1)->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use closer.

```
  item::where('isAvaliable', 1)
          ->where('t_Id', 2)
          ->where(function($q) {
              $q->where('isBeautiful', 1)
                ->orWhere('isGreat', 1);
          })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's query builder also accepts a Closure.

So, something like this should work:

```
$availableItems = item::where('isAvailable',1)
                       ->where(function($query)) {
                            $query->whereNull('isBeautiful', 1)
                                  ->orWhere('isGreat', 1)
                       })
                       ->get();
```